# Multilingual toolkit for shared project not generating resw file

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal, multilingual-app-toolkit

I use resources in shared project for Win8.1 and UWP. I added different language translation by using [multilingual app toolkit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/mat.aspx), that successfully creating the xlf file.

But when I make a release build, the resw is not been translated and it all stays in English without any value.

I use the latest version of Multilingual App Toolkit Ver.4.0
The Resw File path juse as the follow image:

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your demo, I will sent to someone to check that

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT Thanks. I figured out, when i removed the <link> from .projitems , it worked

Comment: Microsoft did comment about that on MSDN. Apparently, it tries to localize the `<link>` tags, which can break the translator.

Comment: @JamesM can you please provide the MSDN link which tells about it.

Comment: `Don’t over localize. Localize specific strings, not tags. Including the above <link> tag in the resources means that it too will be localized. This renders the tag not valid. Only the strings themselves should be localized. Generally, you should think of tags as code that should be kept separate from localizable content.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/prepare-your-app-for-localization